# Input type = "file" multiple | select multiple files

Tags: javascript, file, select, input

can you tell me how I in `<input type = "file" multiple>` that it can make when selecting a file and then go and have a file selects it the other remains listed?

can you send me a javascript for example? Or do I have to use what else?

e.g.

You select a file:

Selected one file

You choose a file from again before pressing upload:

Selected 2 files

Hopefully you understand what I mean. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`<input type = "file" multiple>` allows you to select multiple files from the same file open dialog (usually with Ctrl+click)
But be careful, this is not supported for older browsers (e.g. IE9)

If you want multiple file open dialogs, you need multiple `<input type = "file">` tags (either statically or dynamically inserted into the webpage)